# resource cannot be found error when launching an asp application

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, http-status-code-404

So I am just in utter disgust at what happened. i was working on an asp.net in TFS application and all of the sudden it literally just stopped working. Every time I tried to launch it in a browser it would display this error:

[image]

The entire DESCRIPTION states:

> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly

I haven't the slightest clue what happened. I have not to my best recollection done anything to jeopardize it.

This is what I've done. since I have two different logins to my computer, I took the solution and tried to launch it in my 2nd login and it worked perfectly. I took that same solution file and tried to launch it in my current login and it's causing this issue.

I reset all my Visual studio settings and tried to launch the solution and again - get the same error.

It is showing the SERVIER ERROR in /HOME.aspx - but this error does not show up in my other login.

Does anyone have any idea what could cause this? I'm basically looking at creating a new user profile for myself to get this resolved. Any help will be much appreciated.

Could it be my user profile or would simply re-installing VS could resolve it?

Comment: Does the solution have more, than one project? Maybe you should look at the set Startup Project-setting!?

Comment: @Nikolaus i just don't understand that the same solution works in one login but not the other